# Oracle XE 18c connects with sqlplus, but not DB GUI apps

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I installed Oracle XE 18c on RHEL on my laptop, got it configured, created connections with two applications (DBeaver and DbVisualizer) as well as able to connect with sqlplus. It all worked "perfectly".

This morning, I had to "IT Crowd" reboot my laptop (turned it off and back on again), then started Oracle XE using sqlplus, accessed a table to confirm the engine actually came up although the appropriate startup messages were generated.

My problem is neither of the DB apps (above) can connect to the XE database again. I've checked the listener.ora file, it matches the connection configuration in both applications for the hostname and port number. The /etc/hosts file still contains the same configuration.

Note that the server is configured in listener.ora to listen on port 1539.

The message I get from both apps when I "ping the server" is effectively the same: "

```
Cannot connect to '<redacted>' on port 1539
```

along with the standard "please check and try again" advice. I can't find any log files with entries for today. It sounds trite, but none of the configuration files changed, the only difference I can see is having rebooted and possibly something did not "stick", perhaps a process did not get started.

Please accept my thanks in advance.

Comment: Is RHEL installed natively on your machine or in a VM? `netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 1521` will tell you which interfaces the listener is up on

Comment: @Phil - nothing is listening on 1521 NOR 1539, which is the configured port (listener.ora).  So I'm a dope, I mean novice, with sqlplus - does it require the engine to access the database?

Comment: @Phil ... its a native install

Comment: Do `lsnrctl start` to start the listener

Comment: @Phil - Thanks!  I'm still puzzled as to why this command was omitted from the Oracle resources I was able to find. I don't see how to up-vote or I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener is not running.

As the Oracle user (which may be called `oracle` or `oraclexe`) run:

```
lsnrctl start
```

... to start the [Oracle listener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netrf/Listener-Control-utility.html#GUID-0A209E02-E1A1-4B2A-9FFF-FD316E9670F3).